# Add minor ticks to custom ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

So as of now I am using

`Ticks -> {Range[0, d, 1]}`

where `d` is the maximum value for my axes.

But the thing is that between 0 and 1 (or other integers) there are no minor ticks. Look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AULeD.jpg).

I have now **only** the integers and empty space in between. All I want is to have like five minor ticks. Just so that it looks better. I want to have the major (labeled) ticks only at the integers.

Also could maybe someone tell me how to **not have** two 0 labels on one plot (one for the x-axis, one for the y-axis)? Again look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AULeD.jpg).

I've spent an hour looking for the solution, but wasn't able to find a good one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Plot[1 + x^2, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 25, {5, 5}], 
    None}, {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 5, {5, 5}], None}}]
```

[image]

To remove one of two ticks with label `0` at the origin use

```
FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0.5, 25, {5, 5}], 
   None}, {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 5, {5, 5}], None}}
```

[image]

You can also create a custom tick function to use with `FrameTicks`:

```
tickFunc = Join[{#, #, {.03, 0}} & /@ Subdivide[##, 5], 
     {#, " ",  {.01, 0}} & /@ Subdivide[##, 25]] &; 

Plot[1 + x^2, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! thank you

Comment: @kglr Trying to extend your first technique for use on a 3D plot gives the error: "A tick position in the value of the Ticks option should be a number." How can your first technique be correctly extended for use with a 3D plot?

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney, this works: ``Plot3D[1 + x^2+y^2, {x, 0, 5},{y, 0,5},
Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0,5, {5, 5}], 
  Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 5, {5, 5}],Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 50, {2, 5}]}]``

Comment: Hey kglr, silly ask for clarification, but I noticed you never answered OP’s second question about the single number for 0 instead of two instances of them—do you have an easy way to extend these methods for that? Some convenient setting possibly?

Comment: @CATrevillian, thank you for bringing this to my attention. I updated with a method that removes one of the duplicate labels at the origin.

Comment: Hi, kglr. I'm trying to apply your method to my question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255896/axesorigin-doesnt-appear-in-plot                 But why the functions that you are using are in blue color in my Mathematica and it does not recognize these functions?

Comment: @Nima, posted an answer to your question. Re blue coloring, internal undocumented functions are styled blue.

Comment: Side note: syntax of ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` has changed a bit in higher versions. See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269044/1871