# How to make Mathematica label the origin when plotting several functions

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I am plotting three functions using the following code:

```
Show[Plot[{2^x + 1}, {x, 3/2, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[{x + 3}, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue], Plot[{2 x^2 + 1}, {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black], PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

In the generated plot, the tick labels are absent at the chosen `AxesOrigin` point `(1,0)`. How can Mathematica be made to label the origin `(1,0)`?

Comment: Add  `Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Red, Point@{1, 0}}`

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry, but your code does not show the tick label of the origin. I want to let Mathematica show the tick of the origin (1, 0).

Comment: Alternatively, use `Frame` instead of `Axes`. Example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190492/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. The answer in this link (mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190492/1871) seems not correct. Mathematica reports error when I run the codes in the answer.

Comment: There's a compatibility issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269044/1871 Alternatively, if you don't need to customize the ticks, simply remove the `FrameTicks` option.

Comment: @xzczd One more question: in some cases, the origin is shown as (0.0, 0.0) when I use the code "PlotRangePadding -> 0". How to make Mathematica show (0, 0) instead of (0.0, 0.0)?

Comment: That's a different problem. Consider starting a new question with concrete code sample reproducing the problem. (And I'd suggest first searching in this site. )

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your answer. I will search on the site to check if there is solution to this problem. If not, I will write a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica's default is not to put a label where axes cross as (I think) it would become too crowded.

A possibility could be to use a `Callout` on a separate plot and adjust the label and styling as needed. There are plenty of options available for `Callout` styling that will not be discussed here.

```
Show[
 Plot[{2^x + 1}, {x, 3/2, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 , Plot[{x + 3}, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 , Plot[{2 x^2 + 1}, {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black]
 , ListPlot[{Callout[{1, 0}, Style["(1,0)", Red]
    , {1.2, -0.6}, {1, 0}]}
  , PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 18, Gray]}]
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-2, 8}}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this proposal is a bit tangential to the question I asked.

Comment: You can show (using a <hand-drawn> image) where and what you are looking for exactly. I see  many responses; each interpreting your question a bit differently.

Comment: It seems I have find the solution to this question. Use `PlotRangePadding -> 0` and `Ticks` to explicitly specify the tick lables.

Answer (score 1):

With a single [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  ConditionalExpression @@@
   {{2^x + 1, 3/2 < x < 3},
    {x + 3, 1 < x < 3},
    {2 x^2 + 1, 1 < x < 2}}],
 {x, 1, 3},
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   {2^x + 1, x + 3, 2 x^2 + 1},
   {0.8, 0.28}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer that the two axes can cross at the origin (1, 0).