# Adding unit square axes to an array plot

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I want to take the image created by ArrayPlot of a matrix A and add axes with the origin at the top left so that the image looks like the density plot of a function on [0,1]^2.

```
    makePic[matrix_] := Block[
  {pic = ArrayPlot[matrix, DataReversed -> True], image},
  image = 
   ImageReflect[
    Graphics[
     Inset[Show[pic, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], 
      Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@pic]];
  Return[image];
  ]
```

By removing the ImageReflect, this produces an almost desireable result, but I want the image to be the arrayPlot. When I reflect the image, I reflect the numbers on the axis. So it is likely that another approach is needed. Anyone know how I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Have you explored the `DataReversed` and `DataRange` options?

Comment: Thank you. I initially used data reversed to make the array plot look like the density plot of the function f[x,y] := matrix[[Ceiling[nx], Ceiling[ny]]] where n is order of the (square) matrix. Then I combined the arrayplot image with an image of the coordinate axes. But I need the origin to appear at the top left (as in Domen's answer). I need the plot of this function to look exactly like array plot, which is why I am using arrayplot instead of density plot). So reversing the data in the arrayplot won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with `FrameTicks` and reversed y-axis. However, you have to change `FrameTicks` *after* using `ArrayPlot`, otherwise `ArayPlot` will reposition them at half-steps.

```
makePic[matrix_] := 
 ArrayPlot[matrix, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 
    0] /. {(FrameTicks -> _) -> (FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[
         "Reverse", "Nice"], None}, {None, All}}), 
   Raster[m_, _, z_] :> Raster[m, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}, z]}

makePic[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}]]
```

[image: ArrayPlot]

Comment: This image is what I want, but I get an error when I try to run this function. The error is: "A ticks specification in the value of FrameTicks should be None, Automatic, a function, or a list of ticks." This may be version related. I am using version 13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)

Comment: @fratepencil, you are right, thanks! The syntax for the undocumented function `Charting`ScaledTicks` has [slightly changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269021/chartingscaledticks-not-working-anymore-in-mathematica-13) in v13. I fixed the code – it should work now.

Comment: I still get the same error on my installation--unsure why. But running it in the cloud works perfectly. If I figure out something that works on my installation I'll give an update. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried the code in `13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows`, and it works fine. Please, try with a fresh kernel (restart with `Quit[]`).

Comment: I restarted the kernel, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hm, weird. Then you can manually provide the ticks. For example: Replace that ``Charting`ScaledTicks[...]`` with `{-#, #} & /@ Subdivide[1., 5]`